# Java BufferedInputStream behavior

Tags: java, inputstream, behavior, bufferedinputstream

Why is the LAST Byte read = 0 if the file size > 8k?

```
private static final int GAP_SIZE = 8 * 1024;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    File tmp = File.createTempFile("gap", ".txt");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tmp);
    out.write(1);
    out.write(new byte[GAP_SIZE]);
    out.write(2);
    out.close();
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(tmp));
    int first = in.read();
    in.skip(GAP_SIZE);
    int last = in.read();
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(last);
}
```

Comment: The actual number of bytes skipped is not guaranteed. You have to check it. Seems that it doesn't want to skip past the native filesystem block size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InputStream API says that the skip method may, for a variety of reasons, end up skipping over some smaller number of bytes.  Try this

```
...
long n = in.skip(GAP_SIZE);
System.out.println(n);
...
```

it prints 8191 instead of expected 8192. This is related to BufferedInputStream implementation details, if you remove it (it doesn't improove performance in this concrete case anyway) you will get the expected result

```
...
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(tmp);
...
```

output

```
1
2
```

Comment: I'm confused... if the cause is the skip method in FileInputStream, why removing BufferedInputStream solves the issue?

Comment: The actual cause is BufferedInputStream implementation details, FileInputStream is OK

Comment: well, you're right, but i'm still confused, as FileInputStream Skip says: "The skip method may, for a variety of reasons, end up skipping over some smaller number of bytes".

Comment: right, in real app we should use skip in a loop until we skip the number we need

Comment: I found the reason: BufferedInputStream has a defaultBufferSize = 8192

Answer (score 1):

As Perception said, you need to check the return of `skip`. If I add a check and compensate it fixes the problem:

```
long skipped = in.skip(GAP_SIZE);
System.out.println( "GAP: " + GAP_SIZE + " skipped: " + skipped ) ;
if( skipped < GAP_SIZE)
{
   skipped = in.skip(GAP_SIZE-skipped);
}
```

As stated in the [`skip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#skip(long)) section for `FileInputStream`:

> The skip method may, for a variety of reasons, end up skipping over some smaller number of bytes, possibly 0